# Tkinter event for DownPress of mouse button (holding down)?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, python-3.6

UPDATE: This seams to be a version issue. The  event does not fire on click for python 3.6.1 but works on 2.7 that I have tested so far.

UPDATE: Bryan's answer did fix my problem with the event not working correctly however the issue of the event not firing on the down-click not work is still an issue on my 3.6.1 version of python.

Python version = `3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]`

I am trying to write an event handler to do something repeatedly while the mouse button is being held down. I have been scouring the documentation and the internet but I cannot find any reference to just holding down the left mouse button.

Is there an event specifically for holding down the left mouse button? There is an even for release `<ButtonRelease-1>` but there does not seam to be one for a click and hold event.

I have tried `<Button-1>` and all of its synonymous events just in case but no luck. The event only fires on release but not on the down click as I want it. I don't even need an event for constantly holding the button I just need an even for the down press only.

Documentation welcome as I can't seam to find any.

UPDATE:

Here is an example code. It will only print when the button is released. Keep in mind I am trying to press the arrow buttons on the scroll bar and to change the speed of scrolling.

Does the scrollbar handle pressing the scroll arrows differently than a button?

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

textbox = tk.Text(root, height = 10)
textbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

scrolling = False
yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=textbox.yview,orient="vertical", repeatinterval=10, repeatdelay=30)
textbox.configure(yscrollcommand = yscroll.set)
yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

for i in range(1000):
    textbox.insert(tk.END, "{}\n".format(i))

def scrolling_active(arrow):
    global scrolling
    root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_scrolling())
    print(arrow)
    if scrolling == True:
        if arrow == "arrow1":
            textbox.tk.call(textbox._w,'yview', 'scroll', -100, 'units')
        if arrow == "arrow2":
            textbox.tk.call(textbox._w,'yview', 'scroll', 100, 'units')
        root.after(100, lambda a = arrow: scrolling_active(a))

def start_scrolling(event):
    global scrolling
    scrolling = True
    scrolling_active(yscroll.identify(event.x, event.y))

def stop_scrolling():
    global scrolling
    scrolling = False

yscroll.bind("<Button-1>", start_scrolling)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event for holding a button down. There are only events for the press and release of a button.

If you need to track while a button is down, you can set a flag on the press and unset it on a release.

In your code, you have a bug. Consider this code:

```
root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_scrolling())
```

It is functionally identical to this:

```
result=stop_scrolling()
root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', None)
```

To do the binding you must remove the `()`:

```
root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_scrolling)
```

You also need `stop_scrolling` to accept the event object:

```
def stop_scrolling(event):
    global scrolling
    scrolling = False
```

Also, there's no need to call `textbox.tk.call`. You can call the `yview` method on the tkinter object (`textbox.yview("scroll", -100, "units"`)

Comment: Hey Bryan. That is my understanding also however it appears that for my version at least of 3.6.1 the events for left mouse click like `<Button-1>` are not firing until I release the mouse click. But they appear to work fine on 2.7. My version is `3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: They work for me on 3.5.2. I find it hard to believe there would be this sort of regression in a point release because it would likely break many, many tkinter scripts. What did you do to verify that the `<Button-1>` event wasn't firing?

Comment: I have a print statement at the start of the function it is suppose to call on. The print statement hits my console on click release for 3.6.1 and on initial click on my 2.7

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: what OS are you running on?

Comment: Windows 7 pro currently. I can test on Linux and windows 10 when I get home.

Comment: The problem may be related to the fact that on windows the scrollbar is a native windows control, and it has it's own event handler. In all my years of programming with tkinter I don't think I've ever bound an event to a scrollbar.

Comment: Well the reason I am working on it is because anther person on stack overflow was trying to increase the speed of the scrolling while holding down the arrow buttons on the scrollbar. I did try to find the event that is called when the arrow1 or arrow2 is activated but could not so I decided to try to write a function to work around it.

Comment: Also I am able to get the actual scrolling with the modified units to work per click just not a continuous scroll while holding down the button.

Comment: I got my program working on 2.7 as intended. I guess there could be a bug in 3.6.1 and the other person who posted an answer said they had the same behavior on 3.6.2

Comment: The problem was a few things not including the issue with 3.6.1 but the main fix was changing `root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_scrolling())` to `root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_scrolling)`

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: you can probably speed up the scrolling by fiddling with the `repeatinterval` option of the scrollbar.

Comment: I did try to work with `repeatinterval` and `repeatdelay` however now that I have the event issue solved I will revisit those 2 and see what I can do with them. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but I wanted to do the exact same thing (drag an image in a canvas to make a joystick controller).

Reading the docs [Events and Bindings](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211515id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) I found this event: **`'<B1-Motion>'`**

Here's the working example I did :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')

image1 = PhotoImage(file = 'images/button.png')
x_img,y_img = 250,250

canvas = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 400, bg = 'white')
canvas.pack()
imageFinal = canvas.create_image(x_img, y_img, image = image1)

def move(event):
    global x_img,y_img
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
    canvas.move(imageFinal, x-x_img,y-y_img)
    x_img = x
    y_img = y
    canvas.update()

canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', move)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can also, just have canvas.create_oval(event.x,event.y,event.x+5,event.y+5) in the move event, to make it kind of act like MS paint

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind to `<ButtonPress-1>` for when the Mouse is initially clicked, and then call a repeating function until `<ButtonRelease-1>` stops it, as you mentioned.

Comment: That does not work. Already tried it. The event doesn't fire until I release the click.

Comment: Are you sure <ButtonPRESS-1> doesn't work? It works perfectly fine for me; triggering as soon as the mouse is clicked.

Comment: I tried all documented versions of left mouse click. All don't work.

Comment: It looks like it could be a version issue. My python 3.6 doesn't work on click but my 2.7 does. I will have to see if its a version issue or my build is broken.

Comment: It is odd that your program worked in Python 2.7 but not in the current version. I also have the same issue (in Python 3.6.2) as you described. I do not have a 2.7 version to test it on though currently.