# Python tkinter left click hold down issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I am sorry for my English. It only detects once when I hold down the left click on the mouse.I want it to detect as long as I hold it down.

```
def Dataprint(event=None):
    UDP_IP_ADDRESS_SERVER = "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx"
    UDP_PORT_SERVER = 7005
    message = "#upto"
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    client.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), (UDP_IP_ADDRESS_SERVER, UDP_PORT_SERVER))
    print("sent")
    time.sleep(0.01)
ttk.Label(TAB2, text="bos",font=("Arial",20),foreground="#fff",borderwidth=2,background="#7b7bc0",width=9).grid(column=0, row=4, padx=10, pady=10)
emptyup=ttk.Button(TAB2,text="up")
emptyup.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=10, pady=10)
emptyup.bind("<Button-1>",Dataprint)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I bind an event to the left mouse button being held down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288001/how-do-i-bind-an-event-to-the-left-mouse-button-being-held-down)
Another useful answer is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46227617/tkinter-event-for-downpress-of-mouse-button-holding-down).

Comment: Nope, i tried them before i don't want Motion

Comment: The selected answer to that linked question doesn't deal with motion.

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand how the linked question will solve my problem, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about tkinter, so I can't provide any code for this. However, I imagine it is because when you `bind`, the function is triggered once only when button is *pressed*, and won't retrigger while it's held.

A solution to this is to call `Dataprint` again at the end of the function and maintaining a global variable (or a field in the class, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288001/how-do-i-bind-an-event-to-the-left-mouse-button-being-held-down)) that indicates whether the user is still holding down the mouse. Something like this:

```py
import time
mouse_is_pressed = False

def Dataprint(event):
    global emptyup
    # ...
    emptyup.after(20, function=None)
    if mouse_is_pressed:
        Dataprint(event)

def start_printing(event=None):
    global mouse_is_pressed
    mouse_is_pressed = True
    Dataprint(event)

def stop_printing(event=None):
    global mouse_is_pressed
    mouse_is_pressed = False

# I am not sure about the exact details, but I am sure you can find out
emptyup.bind("<Button-1>", start_printing)
emptyup.bind("<B1-Release>", stop_printing)
```

See if this works. I replaced `time.sleep` with `.after` from tkinter since `time.sleep` blocks the thread - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method).

Comment: Almost works, this time Dataprint is working non-stop. Thank you for answer

Comment: After replacements still not working

Comment: It's keep stucking because of "if mouse_is_pressed:Dataprint(event)"

Comment: Make it asynchronous

Comment: What do you mean with "Make it asynchronous" can you be more clear?